# Can the word "he" be used to refer to a woman?

Tags: pronouns, lyrics

In the song “[Extraordinary Girl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOp5V9uzJrY)” by Green Day, you can notice that the vocalist sings about an “extraordinary girl”, sometimes referring to her as *he*, and sometimes as *she*.

For example, at 2:51, you can hear:

> Some days *he* feels like dying, some days it's not worth trying … *she* gets so sick of crying.

As far as I know, only *she* can be used to refer to a female. Is using *he* to refer to a female valid?

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: Once again, [interpreting song lyrics is Off Topic](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3170/why-is-the-meaning-of-song-lyrics-off-topic)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn't ask for, just, in case, my question's source was in that song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is about two people, a male and a female of indeterminate age, not just the extraordinary girl. She's great but he's a wimp.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, as I understand, "he" cannot be referred to girl?

Comment: "Cannot" is too strong, but in ordinary circumstances (like this song) "he" refers to a male and "she" refers to a female.

Comment: Ah......Well, that's not necessarily true: there are many cases of transgender and transsexual people being referred to by both pronouns because there's a moral, ethical, religious, or legal dispute about which gender the person really is, especially when they haven't had a sex-change operation. However, it's generally true.

Answer (score 1):

The song is about a girl and a boy. That's why there's a *he* and a *she*.

On a different note, many song writers skip some grammar rules to maintain the rhythm of their songs. This is allowed in any language and is called **[Poetic License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license)** That's why you see some grammatically wrong phrases in song lyrics which rhyme with the song.